# php return statement fails to return correct values,how to solve it?

Tags: php

I have created a public function to call and return commission rates. Everything works well except for one service. I want its return value to check for these values before assigning a commission rate:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Amount<100000 then 650 ELSE 1000 END )
```

I tried: 
`$TRA_TRAN_RATE=SUM( WHEN Amount<100000 then 650 ELSE 1000 END )`

but it returns this error:

> syntax error, unexpected 'Amount' (T_STRING)

Can anyone give me an idea how to solve it? Here's the function I made:

```
 //retrieve the commission rates
    public function com_rate($key){
        $free_rate = 0.04;
        $TRA_TRAN_RATE=SUM( WHEN Amount<100000 then 650 ELSE 1000 END )
        switch($key){
            case 'E_RATE': return 0.25;break;
            case 'T_RATE': return 0.01;break;
            case 'D_RATE': return 0.0075;break;
            case 'E_T_RATE': return 0.03;break;
            case 'ET_RATE': return $free_rate;break;
            case 'N_RATE': return $free_rate;break;
            case 'TRA_TRAN_RATE': return $TRA_TRAN_RATE;break;
```

//error come from here

Comment: `$TRA_TRAN_RATE` is a string and should be quoted.

Comment: `$TRA_TRAN_RATE = SUM( WHEN Amount<100000 then 650 ELSE 1000 END );`

Comment: There is no need to put `break` after a `return`. [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) returns the program control (and, optionally, a value) to the code that called the function. No other statement of the function is executed after `return`. All the `break` statements in the posted fragment are dead code (unreachable code).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing mysql and php; you are trying to assign a sql expression to a php variable:

```
$TRA_TRAN_RATE=SUM( WHEN Amount<100000 then 650 ELSE 1000 END )
```

In php you can use a ternary expression:

```
$TRA_TRAN_RATE = $Amount < 100000 ? 650 : 1000;
```

Assuming that the amount is stored in the `$Amount` variable. As that is undefined in the scope of your function, you would need to send it as an extra parameter / do a database query / etc.

Comment: let me try your solution,tanx for your reply

Comment: i fetch the amount direct from sql server database @jeroen

Comment: $TRA_TRAN_RATE = $Amount < 100000 ? 650 : 1000; this works but it generates wrong values,it takes 650%

Comment: @BonyMassele These are the values you set in your code, you should adapt them to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, you are using some DB connections and retrieving data and so... I Thing your code must looks like this (Yes this connection is deprecated but you can investigate appropriate links and write with new way)

```
<?php
//retrieve the commission rates
    function com_rate($key){
        $free_rate = 0.04;
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM( WHEN Amount < 100000 then 650 ELSE 1000 END ) sum FROM TABLE");
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($TRA_TRAN_RATE);
        $TRA_TRAN_RATE = $result['sum'];

        //or with this way
        //$TRA_TRAN_RATE = mysql_result("SELECT SUM( WHEN Amount < 100000 then 650 ELSE 1000 END ) sum FROM TABLE",1);

        switch($key){
            case 'E_RATE': return 0.25;break;
            case 'T_RATE': return 0.01;break;
            case 'D_RATE': return 0.0075;break;
            case 'E_T_RATE': return 0.03;break;
            case 'ET_RATE': return $free_rate;break;
            case 'N_RATE': return $free_rate;break;
            case 'TRA_TRAN_RATE': return $TRA_TRAN_RATE;break;
        }
    }

    echo com_rate('ET_RATE');

?>
```

Comment: yes your right am using db connection to retrieve data using sqlsrv so this mysql quaries will not do well for me

Answer (score 0):

wrap your sql aggregate function to a quote then add `CASE` before `WHEN` to correct your ternary condition in mysql

```
$TRA_TRAN_RATE=SUM( WHEN Amount<100000 then 650 ELSE 1000 END )
```

to

```
$TRA_TRAN_RATE='SUM( CASE WHEN Amount<100000 then 650 ELSE 1000 END )'
```